# Sudden error on MobileAds.initialize using Android Studio

Tags: android, admob

I have a published application that works correctly and has over 100k downloads. And now I'm working on an update, but suddenly there appeared an error in the MobileAds.initialize line that has nothing to do with the actualization I'm working on and I'm lost. I do not know where to look.

I use Android Studio 3.1.4, API 27 and test on Samsung Note 8 device. My operational system is Debian 9.

The application is breaking exactly on the MobileAds.initialize line with the error "A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: GetStringUTFChars received NULL jstring
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]     in call to GetStringUTFChars"

It sounds like something related to creating the AdMob WebView. But I do not know where to start.

If I comment on all rows pertaining to AdMob the application works perfectly.

Here is the code snippet for AdMob startup (using firebase)

```
//ADMOB
try {
    MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "my_admob_id");
} catch (Exception e) {
    Logs.e(TAG, "Erro inicia adMob "+e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Gradle to import firebase

```
//ADMob
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
```

And finally the error log.

```
08-16 18:18:14.698 9012-9012/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
08-16 18:18:14.699 9012-9012/? W/SELinux: SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 RAM:SEPF_SM-N950F_8.0.0_0002, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1]
08-16 18:18:14.699 9012-9012/? I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.bonino.tabuamare 
08-16 18:18:14.702 9012-9012/? I/zygote64: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
08-16 18:18:14.783 9012-9012/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
08-16 18:18:14.893 9012-9012/com.bonino.tabuamare I/zygote64: no shared libraies, dex_files: 1
08-16 18:18:14.915 9012-9056/com.bonino.tabuamare I/vndksupport: sphal namespace is not configured for this process. Loading /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so from the current namespace instead.
08-16 18:18:14.918 9012-9018/com.bonino.tabuamare I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=21KB
08-16 18:18:14.919 9012-9018/com.bonino.tabuamare I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=30KB, data=21KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
08-16 18:18:14.942 9012-9056/com.bonino.tabuamare D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so
08-16 18:18:14.954 9012-9012/com.bonino.tabuamare V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
08-16 18:18:14.955 9012-9012/com.bonino.tabuamare D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
    com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
08-16 18:18:14.956 9012-9012/com.bonino.tabuamare I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
08-16 18:18:15.009 9012-9012/com.bonino.tabuamare V/FA: onActivityCreated
08-16 18:18:15.036 9012-9064/com.bonino.tabuamare V/FA: Collection enabled
08-16 18:18:15.037 9012-9064/com.bonino.tabuamare V/FA: App package, google app id: com.bonino.tabuamare, 1:673217711876:android:ecd2f6ab25e33ce0
08-16 18:18:15.038 9012-9064/com.bonino.tabuamare I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 12780
    To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
08-16 18:18:15.038 9012-9064/com.bonino.tabuamare I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.bonino.tabuamare
08-16 18:18:15.038 9012-9064/com.bonino.tabuamare D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
08-16 18:18:15.079 9012-9064/com.bonino.tabuamare V/FA: Connecting to remote service
08-16 18:18:15.085 9012-9074/com.bonino.tabuamare D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
08-16 18:18:15.094 9012-9012/com.bonino.tabuamare D/ViewRootImpl@ba9a2ed[SplashActivity]: setView = DecorView@c0a80e9[SplashActivity] TM=true MM=false
08-16 18:18:15.116 9012-9012/com.bonino.tabuamare D/ViewRootImpl@ba9a2ed[SplashActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
08-16 18:18:15.131 9012-9064/com.bonino.tabuamare V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
08-16 18:18:15.132 9012-9064/com.bonino.tabuamare I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
08-16 18:18:15.140 9012-9012/com.bonino.tabuamare V/Surface: sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
08-16 18:18:15.141 9012-9012/com.bonino.tabuamare D/ViewRootImpl@ba9a2ed[SplashActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][0,0] new=[0,0][1080,2220] result=0x7 surface={valid=true 522215149568} changed=true
08-16 18:18:15.144 9012-9064/com.bonino.tabuamare D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SplashActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3722170161791671853}]
08-16 18:18:15.150 9012-9074/com.bonino.tabuamare I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-16 18:18:15.151 9012-9074/com.bonino.tabuamare D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
08-16 18:18:15.153 9012-9074/com.bonino.tabuamare D/libGLESv1: STS_GLApi : DTS, ODTC are not allowed for Package : com.bonino.tabuamare
08-16 18:18:15.154 9012-9012/com.bonino.tabuamare D/ViewRootImpl@ba9a2ed[SplashActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2220) ci=Rect(0, 63 - 0, 126) vi=Rect(0, 63 - 0, 126) or=1
    MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
08-16 18:18:15.155 9012-9074/com.bonino.tabuamare D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, egl_color_buffer_format *, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1080x2220]-format:1
08-16 18:18:15.155 9012-9074/com.bonino.tabuamare D/OpenGLRenderer: eglCreateWindowSurface = 0x799e026b40
08-16 18:18:15.155 9012-9012/com.bonino.tabuamare V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@e86421 nm : com.bonino.tabuamare ic=null
08-16 18:18:15.155 9012-9012/com.bonino.tabuamare I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
08-16 18:18:15.202 9012-9064/com.bonino.tabuamare V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
08-16 18:18:15.203 9012-9064/com.bonino.tabuamare V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
    Activity resumed, time: 967997297
08-16 18:18:15.270 9012-9012/com.bonino.tabuamare V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@21e30cc nm : com.bonino.tabuamare ic=null
08-16 18:18:15.270 9012-9012/com.bonino.tabuamare D/BaseDados: initBaseDados
08-16 18:18:15.294 9012-9064/com.bonino.tabuamare D/FA: Connected to remote service
08-16 18:18:15.296 9012-9064/com.bonino.tabuamare V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
08-16 18:18:15.339 9012-9012/com.bonino.tabuamare V/FA: onActivityCreated
08-16 18:18:15.359 9012-9018/com.bonino.tabuamare I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=59KB, data=40KB
08-16 18:18:15.362 9012-9018/com.bonino.tabuamare I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=59KB, data=40KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
08-16 18:18:15.376 9012-9064/com.bonino.tabuamare V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 308
08-16 18:18:15.379 9012-9064/com.bonino.tabuamare V/FA: Activity paused, time: 967997525
08-16 18:18:15.441 9012-9012/com.bonino.tabuamare W/zygote64: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
08-16 18:18:15.507 9012-9012/com.bonino.tabuamare I/zygote64: find the special shared library, skip check
08-16 18:18:15.508 9012-9012/com.bonino.tabuamare I/zygote64: find the special shared library, skip check
08-16 18:18:15.575 9012-9012/com.bonino.tabuamare W/zygote64: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
08-16 18:18:15.587 9012-9012/com.bonino.tabuamare D/DynamitePackage: Instantiated singleton DynamitePackage.
    Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraMobileAdsSettingManagerCreatorImpl
08-16 18:18:15.628 9012-9185/com.bonino.tabuamare D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
08-16 18:18:15.657 9012-9012/com.bonino.tabuamare I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 64.0.3282.137 (code 328213700)
08-16 18:18:15.896 9012-9012/com.bonino.tabuamare E/linker: normalize_path - invalid input: "null", the input path should be absolute
08-16 18:18:15.896 9012-9012/com.bonino.tabuamare W/linker: Warning: unable to normalize "null"
08-16 18:18:15.922 9012-9012/com.bonino.tabuamare A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: GetStringUTFChars received NULL jstring
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]     in call to GetStringUTFChars
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]     from int android.webkit.WebViewFactory.nativeLoadWithRelroFile(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x747e3dd0 self=0x79a8abfa00
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | sysTid=9012 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x79ae3619c8
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | state=R schedstat=( 750774085 17685266 409 ) utm=65 stm=9 core=5 HZ=100
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | stack=0x7fd4d98000-0x7fd4d9a000 stackSize=8MB
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #00 pc 00000000003aeab4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+212)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #01 pc 000000000047e1dc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMapb+348)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #02 pc 00000000002e61b0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+1040)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #03 pc 00000000002e6654  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortVEPKcS2_St9__va_list+116)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #04 pc 000000000010b5dc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck6AbortFEPKcz+172)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #05 pc 000000000010ab60  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck13CheckInstanceERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessENS0_12InstanceKindEP8_jobjectb+832)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #06 pc 000000000010937c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck5CheckERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEbPKcPNS_12JniValueTypeE+860)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #07 pc 0000000000112a78  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI22GetStringCharsInternalEPKcP7_JNIEnvP8_jstringPhbb+648)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #08 pc 0000000000001030  /system/lib64/libwebviewchromium_loader.so (???)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #09 pc 0000000000f7b98c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_webkit_WebViewFactory_nativeLoadWithRelroFile__Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_ClassLoader_2+284)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.nativeLoadWithRelroFile(Native method)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.loadNativeLibrary(WebViewFactory.java:705)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass(WebViewFactory.java:412)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:211)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   - locked <0x0a145760> (a java.lang.Object)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.webkit.WebView.getFactory(WebView.java:2467)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java:2462)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:2527)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4829)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5015)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:597)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:636)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:581)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:564)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:551)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:541)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.v.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874023@12.8.74 (040400-204998136):1)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.q.call(unavailable:5)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.bp.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874023@12.8.74 (040400-204998136):23)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874023@12.8.74 (040400-204998136):8)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.q.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874023@12.8.74 (040400-204998136):7)
08-16 18:18:15.922 9012-9012/com.bonino.tabuamare A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.z.run(unavailable:5)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ad.execute(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874023@12.8.74 (040400-204998136):4)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.y.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874023@12.8.74 (040400-204998136):17)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.y.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874023@12.8.74 (040400-204998136):27)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   - locked <0x0188a419> (a java.lang.Object)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.function.b.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874023@12.8.74 (040400-204998136):4)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ac.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874023@12.8.74 (040400-204998136):55)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ac.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874023@12.8.74 (040400-204998136):4)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ax.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874023@12.8.74 (040400-204998136):55)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.bc.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874023@12.8.74 (040400-204998136):40)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at mu.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874023@12.8.74 (040400-204998136):12)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:612)
08-16 18:18:15.922 9012-9012/com.bonino.tabuamare A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzej.transactAndReadExceptionReturnVoid(unavailable:-1)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzll.zza(unavailable:-1)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzmb.zza(unavailable:-1)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   - locked <0x0d83acde> (a java.lang.Object)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(unavailable:-1)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(unavailable:-1)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.bonino.tabuamare.PrincipalActivity.onCreate(PrincipalActivity.java:71)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7174)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
08-16 18:18:15.923 9012-9012/com.bonino.tabuamare A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java:-1)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6940)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504] 
    runtime.cc:508] Runtime aborting...
    runtime.cc:508] 
    runtime.cc:516] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: GetStringUTFChars received NULL jstring
    runtime.cc:516]     in call to GetStringUTFChars
    runtime.cc:516]     from int android.webkit.WebViewFactory.nativeLoadWithRelroFile(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader)
    runtime.cc:516] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
    runtime.cc:516]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x747e3dd0 self=0x79a8abfa00
    runtime.cc:516]   | sysTid=9012 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x79ae3619c8
    runtime.cc:516]   | state=R schedstat=( 750774085 17685266 409 ) utm=65 stm=9 core=5 HZ=100
    runtime.cc:516]   | stack=0x7fd4d98000-0x7fd4d9a000 stackSize=8MB
    runtime.cc:516]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
    runtime.cc:516]   native: #00 pc 00000000003aeab4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+212)
    runtime.cc:516]   native: #01 pc 000000000047e1dc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMapb+348)
    runtime.cc:516]   native: #02 pc 00000000002e61b0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+1040)
    runtime.cc:516]   native: #03 pc 00000000002e6654  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortVEPKcS2_St9__va_list+116)
    runtime.cc:516]   native: #04 pc 000000000010b5dc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck6AbortFEPKcz+172)
    runtime.cc:516]   native: #05 pc 000000000010ab60  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck13CheckInstanceERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessENS0_12InstanceKindEP8_jobjectb+832)
    runtime.cc:516]   native: #06 pc 000000000010937c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck5CheckERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEbPKcPNS_12JniValueTypeE+860)
    runtime.cc:516]   native: #07 pc 0000000000112a78  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI22GetStringCharsInternalEPKcP7_JNIEnvP8_jstringPhbb+648)
    runtime.cc:516]   native: #08 pc 0000000000001030  /system/lib64/libwebviewchromium_loader.so (???)
    runtime.cc:516]   native: #09 pc 0000000000f7b98c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_webkit_WebViewFactory_nativeLoadWithRelroFile__Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_ClassLoader_2+284)
    runtime.cc:516]   at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.nativeLoadWithRelroFile(Native method)
    runtime.cc:516]   at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.loadNativeLibrary(WebViewFactory.java:705)
    runtime.cc:516]   at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass(WebViewFactory.java:412)
    runtime.cc:516]   at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:211)
    runtime.cc:516]   - locked <0x0a145760> (a java.lang.Object)
    runtime.cc:516]   at android.webkit.WebView.getFactory(WebView.java:2467)
    runtime.cc:516]   at android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java:2462)
    runtime.cc:516]   at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:2527)
    runtime.cc:516]   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4829)
    runtime.cc:516]   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5015)
    runtime.cc:516]   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:597)
    runtime.cc:516]   at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
    runtime.cc:516]   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:636)
    runtime.cc:516]   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:581)
    runtime.cc:516]   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:564)
    runtime.cc:516]   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:551)
    runtime.cc:516]   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:541)
    runtime.cc:516]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.v.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874023@12.8.74 (040400-204998136):1)
    runtime.cc:516]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.q.call(unavailable:5)
    runtime.cc:516]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.bp.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874023@12.8.74 (040400-204998136):23)
    runtime.cc:516]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874023@12.8.74 (040400-204998136):8)
    runtime.cc:516]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.q.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874023@12.8.74 (040400-204998136):7)
    runtime.cc:516]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.z.run(unavailable:5)
    runtime.cc:516]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ad.execute(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874023@12.8.74 (040400-204998136):4)
    runtime.cc:516]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.y.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874023@12.8.74 (040400-204998136):17)
    runtime.cc:516]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.y.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874023@12.8.74 (040400-204998136):27)
    runtime.cc:516]   - locked <0x0188a419> (a java.lang.Object)
    runtime.cc:516]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.function.b.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874023@12.8.74 (040400-204998136):4)
    runtime.cc:516]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ac.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874023@12.8.74 (040400-204998136):55)
    runtime.cc:516]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ac.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874023@12.8.74 (040400-204998136):4)
    runtime.cc:516]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ax.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874023@12.8.74 (040400-204998136):55)
    runtime.cc:516]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.bc.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874023@12.8.74 (040400-204998136):40)
    runtime.cc:516]   at mu.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874023@12.8.74 (040400-204998136):12)
    runtime.cc:516]   at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:612)
    runtime.cc:516]   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzej.transactAndReadExceptionReturnVoid(unavailable:-1)
    runtime.cc:516]   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzll.zza(unavailable:-1)
    runtime.cc:516]   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzmb.zza(unavailable:-1)
    runtime.cc:516]   - locked <0x0d83acde> (a java.lang.Object)
    runtime.cc:516]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(unavailable:-1)
    runtime.cc:516]   at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(unavailable:-1)
    runtime.cc:516]   at com.bonino.tabuamare.PrincipalActivity.onCreate(PrincipalActivity.java:71)
    runtime.cc:516]   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7174)
    runtime.cc:516]   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
    runtime.cc:516]   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
    runtime.cc:516]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
    runtime.cc:516]   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java:-1)
    runtime.cc:516]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
    runtime.cc:516]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    runtime.cc:516]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    runtime.cc:516]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6940)
    runtime.cc:516]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
    runtime.cc:516]   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    runtime.cc:516]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
    runtime.cc:516] 
08-16 18:18:15.923 9012-9012/com.bonino.tabuamare A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 9012 (onino.tabuamare)
08-16 18:18:15.923 9012-9012/com.bonino.tabuamare A/zygote64: runtime.cc:516]
```

Thanks for all help,

Ricardo

Comment: The weirdest, using a Genymotion emulator, the app works and starts AdMob, but on my Samsung Note 8 does not work, the app breaks and does not start. I don't have other phisical devices to test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android things. Google solve the issue that they created. kkk

I just receive a update from Google Play Store for the Android System WebView. After this update, the AdMob is working again.

Google likes to make me lose my hair.

Comment: Why don't you add your Admob application id to your manifest and let the com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads library initialize it for you?

Comment: GabrielBB, Admob is already in my manifest. This errors only occurs in some Samsung Galaxy devices. After Google update the WebView, the app start to work again. Didn't need to do nothing on app code.